# Setting Default Value in Bootstrap Drop Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an app with Bootstrap. In this app, I have a control that converts a value between imperial and metric values. To accomplish this, I currently have the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>  
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" data-type="lb">Pounds</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-type="kg">Kilograms</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input id="theValue" type="hidden" data-start-type="kg" />
</div>
```

When the control `theValue` element is populated from the server, it will either be "lb" or "kg". I want to make it so that the selected menu option is based on the value of `theValue` when the page initially loads. In other words, I do not want to see the text "Action". Instead, I need to select either Pounds or Kilograms when the view loads.

How do I do this from jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you would select the `theValue` element, access its `data-start-type` attribute, find the `a` element with the same `data-type` attribute, and then use its `text` value to set the text of the button. You'll want a unique way to identify the button for selection in jQuery, so give it an `id`; I used "actionButton".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data_start_type = $('#theValue').attr('data-start-type');
    var $data_type_elem = $('[data-type='+data_start_type+']');
    $('#actionButton').text($data_type_elem.text());
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7g9k2dwx/

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to match the problem described int he question. I do not see how it is setting the value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I hadn't completely woken up yet and I totally misread your question. Check out this fiddle, is this what you're looking for?  (added bootstrap css and JS) http://jsfiddle.net/cw0p4f4L/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! The selector kept throwing me off. I sincerely appreciate your help.