# Set Default Drop Down Value in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am new to JS and would like to set a default value when the page loads. My HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div class="dropdown" id="country_select">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
          data-toggle="dropdown">Country<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#" country-code="C1">Country1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" country-code="C2">Country2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" country-code="C3">Country3</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
     </body>
```

I have tried some suggestions from similar questions but these do not work in my case.The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210921/setting-default-value-in-bootstrap-drop-down) one is:

```
    var main = function(){
        var data_start_type = "C1";
        var $data_type_elem = $('[country-code='+data_start_type+']');
        $('#country_select li a').text($data_type_elem.text());

    $("#country_select li a").on("click", function () {
            var country_selected=$(this).text();
            Shiny.onInputChange('this_country', country_selected);  //send selected data to the server script
    });
};

    $(document).ready(main);
```

The code above sets all the options of the drop down as 'Country1'. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474857/select-default-value-in-drop-down-bootstrap-3) suggestion that I put this below my JS code but it does not set any default value.

```
$('#country_select li a')[2].click();
```

Could someone please point out how I can fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474857/select-default-value-in-drop-down-bootstrap-3/28523657#28523657

Answer (score 0):

You want be able to do this with a list, since a list is not made for dropdown-menues.

Try this:

```
<select>
<option>.....</option>
<option selected="selected">Select a language</option>
<option>.....</option>
<option>.....</option>
<option>.....</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That could be an option but I am particularly interested in how to do it while using the bootstrap class that I have used above. This is so that I can make use of other bootstrap features that I might not have with the `<select></select>` option.

Comment: You can use any bootstrap features with the <select> option. It's almost like a list but already optimized for dropdowns.

Comment: Considering this `<select></select>` option gives the option set with `selected="defaultoption"` by default on the select button. Problem is that I have to click an option to trigger an event. Do I need to make some changes on the js for the event of selecting the default to get triggered automatically on page load? I am using `$("#country_select").on("change", function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you placed your code correctly?

```
var main = function(){
    var $menu_items = $("#country_select li a");

    $menu_items.on("click", function () {
        Shiny.onInputChange('this_country', $(this).text());
    });
    $menu_items[0].click(); // 0 for Country1, 1 for Country2, etc
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

**Edit:** Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpXavw?editors=1011). If you open the Console at the bottom, you'll see the default value.

Comment: I have tried but that did not work . To investigate that, I tried to send `$menu_items[1].text()` to the server and print it out on the UI but it seems to have no value in it

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question and post more of your code.

Comment: I have provided more code. In, patricular what I have in the `<head>`. The demo on the codepen.io works but when I put the same code on my local machine it does not work as expected. ie. no pre-selected values. could it be due to the some functions loaded in the `<head>`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Are there any errors on the console? If it's sending something to the server, what shows on the network tab of your developer tool?

Comment: To test if `$menuItems[1].click();` works I've added an alert inside `$menuItems.on("click", function() {...}` as `alert("preselected value!");`. The alert comes up once at page loaded. In addition I printed on the UI the pre-selected value `$(this).text()` which prints this value on the UI. This proves that pre-selection works. Thus, the issue is with `Shiny.onInputChange()` not sending anything to the server unless I manually click. I think I should post a new question addressing the issue with the `Shiny.onInputChange()` now that I've confirmed that pre-selection has actually worked